# Does ARM assume that all Cortex-M microcontrollers are little-endian?

Tags: c, arm, bit, endianness, cortex-m

I am currently working on [generating C++ code from SVD files](https://github.com/amosnier/ecg).

While researching what I could assume on bit-field layout in the ARM Application Binary Interface, I came across [ARM's official C header file for the Cortex-M7 core](https://github.com/ARM-software/CMSIS_5/blob/develop/CMSIS/Core/Include/core_cm7.h) (commit [10a6d292f2](https://github.com/ARM-software/CMSIS_5/commit/10a6d292f2acd8fd4ce8937f419927def7402246) at the time of writing).

It contains the following code:

```
/**
  \brief  Union type to access the Application Program Status Register (APSR).
 */
typedef union
{
  struct
  {
    uint32_t _reserved0:16;              /*!< bit:  0..15  Reserved */
    uint32_t GE:4;                       /*!< bit: 16..19  Greater than or Equal flags */
    uint32_t _reserved1:7;               /*!< bit: 20..26  Reserved */
    uint32_t Q:1;                        /*!< bit:     27  Saturation condition flag */
    uint32_t V:1;                        /*!< bit:     28  Overflow condition code flag */
    uint32_t C:1;                        /*!< bit:     29  Carry condition code flag */
    uint32_t Z:1;                        /*!< bit:     30  Zero condition code flag */
    uint32_t N:1;                        /*!< bit:     31  Negative condition code flag */
  } b;                                   /*!< Structure used for bit  access */
  uint32_t w;                            /*!< Type      used for word access */
} APSR_Type;

/* APSR Register Definitions */
#define APSR_N_Pos                         31U                                            /*!< APSR: N Position */
#define APSR_N_Msk                         (1UL << APSR_N_Pos)                            /*!< APSR: N Mask */
```

I intentionally include the first bit mask after the union, because it confirms what the [ARM®v7-M Architecture Reference Manual](https://static.docs.arm.com/ddi0403/eb/DDI0403E_B_armv7m_arm.pdf) specifies: the N-bit, aka "Negative condition code flag", is always the most significant bit of that register, regardless of endianness. This is also quite clear from the comment for the corresponding bit-field.

ARM probably assumes that any compiler that compiles that code for a Cortex-M7 target fulfills the [Procedure Call Standard for the Arm® Architecture](https://developer.arm.com/docs/ihi0042/g/procedure-call-standard-for-the-arm-architecture-abi-2018q4-documentation), which seems like a  reasonable assumption.

That ABI specifies (among others):

> A sequence of bit-fields is laid out in the order declared [...].

This means that bit-field N in the `struct` above will always be laid out as the last bit of the register in memory.

However, if the processor is big-endian, bit-field N in the `struct` above will in that case be the least significant bit of the register, i.e. bit 0, not bit 31!

I find neither comments nor any compile-time flag that would take care of this issue in [core_cm7.h](https://github.com/ARM-software/CMSIS_5/blob/develop/CMSIS/Core/Include/core_cm7.h).

In fact, I have just found [another piece of ARM-code](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0472i/CHDHCIEE.html) that seems to confirm my analysis:

```
#ifndef __BIG_ENDIAN // bitfield layout of APSR is sensitive to endianness
typedef union
{
    struct
    {
        int mode:5;
        int T:1;
        int F:1;
        int I:1;
        int _dnm:19;
        int Q:1;
        int V:1;
        int C:1;
        int Z:1;
        int N:1;
    } b;
    unsigned int word;
} PSR;
#else /* __BIG_ENDIAN */
typedef union
{
    struct 
    {
        int N:1;
        int Z:1;
        int C:1;
        int V:1;
        int Q:1;
        int _dnm:19;
        int I:1;
        int F:1;
        int T:1;
        int mode:5;
    } b;
    unsigned int word;
} PSR;
#endif /* __BIG_ENDIAN */
```

That's obviously for a different core (not Cortex, I'm guessing), but it confirms the principle.

So does ARM just assume that there will never be any big-endian Cortex-M processor, or am I missing something?

Comment: Note that bit-endianess not necessarily need to follow to byte endianess. `So does ARM just assume` Ask ARM. I don't think this is a good place to communicate with ARM developers.

Comment: @KamilCuk, I mean byte-endianness. The ABI for bit fields, on the other hand, speaks about fields that could be as narrow as one bit. In a big-endian processor, bit-field N might not be bit 0, you are right, but it will never be bit 31, which is my main point. You could be right about the forum too. But my thinking is: can I really be the first person who notices this discrepancy?

Comment: Nobody would start building new big-endian architectures today. Little-endian has won, and since the choice is *entirely* arbitrary, there is no value proposition to using the less-common variant. It's *much* better to include a single byte-order swapping instruction (`REV Rd, Rm` in cortexm3/m4)  to enable efficient processing of legacy (network) protocols that require the wrong endianness.

Comment: @EOF, thanks a lot for your insight.

Comment: first off bitfields have nothing to do with endianness, it is implementation defined by the compiler as well as alignment so one should never use bitfields.  memory is cheap the 1970s ended a long time ago.  Improper use of unions and structures like this also falls into the implementation defined category for the language, one should never point structures or worse unions across compile domains as these imply.    And here again with unions memory is cheap even in an mcu, the 1970s ended a long time ago.  These are good interview questions (of what not to do and why).

Comment: the xscale which came in with part of DEC defaulted to big endian, for some reason ti and not sure if others was leaning toward big endian for the cortex-r implementation although they sold both big and little versions of that design.  Arm changed from be32 to be8 around armv6 so then there is that.  With the xscales I used I think you can run little, marvell I think bought those from intel as well as using arm cores from arm.  the ti cortex-rs I dont think you can thus the need for two flavors.  the world is little endian assume as such esp from companies like arm, but....

Comment: remember the chip vendor implements the actual memory interface and can choose the default, etc, so it is not completely an arm question.  As far as thumb2 extensions to the thumb instruction set those are going to little halfword first so even if implemented as a big endian backend the processor needs to be fed the first halfword first.  With be8 though in armv6 and armv7 I believe data accesses vs instruction accesses are different and the instruction accesses have to arrive properly so that is on the toolchain.

Comment: "ARMv7-M supports a selectable endian model in which, on a reset, a control input determines whether the endianness is big endian (BE) or little endian (LE)"......."The AIRCR.ENDIANNESS bit indicates the endianness".....as I mentioned above the chip vendor chooses the endianness implementation.  Other than ti on a non-cortex-m and the xscales, I have not seen a cortex-m (nor full sized) big endian, from the major players, st, nxp, atmel, etc...doesnt mean there isnt another one somewhere...but it would not be in their best interest.

Comment: @old_timer, I'm not following some of your arguments. "Bit-fields have nothing to do with endianness". My second example in the OP (from ARM) seems to disagree with you. "Memory is cheap": in the case we are discussing, the union is to give the choice between bit-access and word-access to a register, not to save memory. I did not write the code, ARM did. And that code is probably included in MANY Cortex-M applications, given that it's a core-file. I'm aware of the drawbacks of using bit-fields. I am also aware of their advantages to access hardware registers. It's a trade-off.

Comment: I have just tried to post the same question in the ARM community forums, but it's been blocked by the moderators. How controversial...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just registered [an issue](https://github.com/ARM-software/CMSIS_5/issues/914) on ARM's CMSIS repository on Github. My assumption right now is that the answer is yes: ARM indeed assumes that all Cortex-M MCUs are and will be little-endian, at least in the code they publish. I hope I will somehow get some confirmation from them. In that case, I will post it here.

Edit:

My assumption above has clearly been confirmed by [one of the answers](https://github.com/ARM-software/CMSIS_5/issues/914#issuecomment-627803443) to [my registered issue](https://github.com/ARM-software/CMSIS_5/issues/914). This is either an overlook, or an undocumented conscious choice, but the result is the same.

To restate the obvious, bit-fields that are used for memory-mapped registers:

- should be very clearly documented. In C and C++, they use implementation-defined behavior, and can therefore only make sense under a particular ABI. Assumptions under which such code is expected to work should clearly be specified.
- assume a certain endianness. This is true under the ARM ABI, but is probably a more general issue. This means that such code needs to have a strategy for asserting that the endianness assumption is correct.

Answer (score -3):

While other architectures have/do have a bit endianness as well as byte/word endianness arm does not as is clearly stated and shown in picture for in their documentation.   But 31 is always bit 31 independent of endianness what byte address bit 31 lands in is what is affected by (byte addressable address) endianness and if it is a register then

> The endianness setting only applies to data accesses. Instruction fetches are always little endian.
>
> All accesses to the SCS are little endian

Default endianness is chosen by the chip vendor not ARM:

> ARMv7-M supports a selectable endian model in which, on a reset, a control input determines whether the endianness is big endian (BE) or little endian (LE).
>
> The AIRCR.ENDIANNESS bit indicates the endianness
>
> Bits[10:8] reset to 0b000 , see register description for more information.

cortex-m7

> Support for ARMv7-M big-endian byte-invariant or little-endian accesses.

I had that backward in my comments, armv7m does show byte invariant, or BE-8 using an arm term.

So the strap pin is not called out in the cortex-m7 trm, didnt look at the m3, m4, m8.

The chip vendor has the biggest role here in how the chip works and what strap options or other compile time options were made for the core.  Then their is their implementation and how well it does or doesn't conform, only the stuff in arms domain is within arms control, outside that it is chip vendor (including bit endianness).

So registers within arms domain should be little endian (if less than word addressable) and bit 31 is bit 31 in the same byte address (if byte addressable).

Bit-fields have nothing to do with any of this they are implementation defined by the compiler author and versions of the language spec (C or C++) have evolved over time but it is still a really bad idea to use bit-fields, you are not that tight on memory if you are using a compiler, the 1970s are over.  You should never point structs nor unions across compile domains as those are implementation defined as well and not target defined nor language defined.  (I use examples like these as interview questions to test the candidates experience and knowledge of the language).  ARM and the chip vendors will clearly and legally state where their code should run and that they have no responsibility for the quality or failures from that code, basically it is all on you, so use code like that with care, and protect yourself, esp if you see this bit-field struct union thing (I normally toss the whole library if they can't get that part right what else to I have to dig for).

So you cannot really devise any theories about what you see in bit-field based code, read the (good/better) documentation from ARM (meaning the architectural reference manual and the technical reference manual.  AMBA/AXI manuals.  The programmers references have been problematic) as well as whatever the chip vendor provides which is often not detailed at that level, and then do experiments for that chip and that core and make no assumptions about other chips from that vendor nor that core used in other products with that core same vendor or not.

The safe play is to go little endian with almost anything arm. xscale is/was an exception I think Marvell bought those from Intel, as well as mixing in cores they buy from arm directly.  I seem to remember the xscale I used could be used little endian, making a big endian gcc toolchain was a nightmare at best.  I have not seen any cortex-ms from the major players, I have many but not all of course, st, nxp, atmel so far I have only seen little endian.  ti has a cortex-r that they offer big or little and you can't switch but those are not cortex-ms.

Stick with little endian with the cortex-ms, if you get screwed by a vendor, 1) that product won't last or was made for a specific customer 2) Blacklist that vendor for that kind of behavior.  Otherwise you should have a happy life and not have to mess with toolchains not working be8 vs be32, internal core registers vs bus accesses to the outside vs external to the core registers implemented by the chip vendor.  There is nothing to indicate that ARM will change it stance on endianness, it would be a bad, possibly fatal, move at this point, think of the endian choices you see in the documentation as marketing bullet points, yes we support big endian and little endian, and not features you would actually use.

Comment: Bit-fields are implementation defined, yes. But in this particular case, their layout is specified by the ARM ABI. And whether a one-bit bit-filed in the last position of a word (from the source code's perspective) will be bit 31 or not in that ABI has a lot to do with endianness! This is clearly confirmed by ARM themselves in the second code example of the OP. Ensuring that core ARM code does not break applications as soon as it is run on a big-endian Cortex-M is very much up to ARM. And their Cortex-M code very much looks like they assume that it will never have to run on a big-endian MCU.

Comment: "Stick with little endian with the cortex-ms". I'm not sure what I am supposed to do with that conclusion. It's not like I select Cortex-M MCUs based on endianness, or like I have a choice once I have selected one. It would just be nice to know why ARM's Cortex-M code seems to assume that Cortex-M MCUs always are little-endian, but doesn't even comment on it. That was my question. And this answer does not answer it.